# Troubleshoot windows error: Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2014-09-13T08:09:23Z. Error Code: 0x80040154

Tags: printing, remote-desktop

My setup:

Opertaing System: Windows 8.1
Memory: 16GB
HD: 500GB
etc. non relevant.

Issue: 
I noticed the issue when my printer stopped working after a normal restart. At that point I tried to uninstall and reinstall the printer driver. The install failed. 
At that point I also realized all my remote desktop connections were also failing, with not being able to find the remote host.

Here is the error I was seeing when install for the printer was failing:
can't start printer spooler service not enough resources are available to start the service

Manually trying to start the spooler service and checking in the event Viewer of windows showed that it was failing on:
Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2014-09-13T08:09:30Z. Error Code: 0x80040154.

Further trying to restart the protection service revealed that it was failing on:
Task Scheduler service has encountered RPC initialization error in "RpcServerUseProtseq:ncacn_ip_tcp". Additional Data: Error Value: 1721.

In either case my computer had become somewhat useless as I couldn't install anything and my printer and remote desktop was broken too.

Reporting the problem just in case if someone has a similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution for my problem is actually posted here, but way back so bringing it to more light:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0c438376-1486-4ae4-9847-2de7a8767f27/task-scheduler-service-has-encountered-rpc-initialization-error-in?forum=itprovistasp

For me what worked was just to starting the prompt in adminstrator mode, running:
netsh winsock reset
and restarting my machine.

Not exactly certain of what actually fixed the issue.